# Find the number for the question mark

Tags: pattern

What is the number for the question mark? (My original puzzle)

3 $\rightarrow$ 39

1 $\rightarrow$ 3

4 $\rightarrow$ 84

5 $\rightarrow$ 155

2 $\rightarrow$ 14

10 $\rightarrow\ \large?$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> By noting that each number maps to a multiple of itself:
> $3\rightarrow3*13$
> $1\rightarrow1*3$
> $4\rightarrow4*21$
> $5\rightarrow5*31$
> $2\rightarrow2*7$
> And that the quotient increases quadratically
> $1:3$
> $2:7=3+4$
> $3:13=7+6$
> $4:21=13+8$
> $5:31=21+10$
> The mapping must be a cubic function.
> The above sequence is equal to $n^2+n+1$, where n is the input.
> The original sequence is multiplied by $n$ again.
> So the function can be described by $n^3+n^2+n$.
> So the final answer is $10^3+10^2+10=1110$.

Comment: It looks like this is it!

Comment: Congratulations

Comment: This was the mathematical way to do what I described in words. Congratulations!

Comment: @El-Guest Thanks, I saw that I started similar to you, but I didn't realise it was the same since you got a different result (but now I know you just miscounted).

Answer (score 8):

Note that

> 1 x 3 = 3 (3 is the 2nd odd positive number) 
>  2 x 7 = 14 (7 is the 4th positive odd number) 
>  3 x 13 = 39 (13 is the 7th positive odd number) 
>  4 x 21 = 84 (21 is the 11th positive odd number) 
>  5 x 31 = 155 (31 is the 16th positive odd number)

Note that

> The nth odd number is being used, where n forms a pattern of 2, 4, 7, 11, 16 — ie. differences increase by one. Then to continue this pattern, we have 22, 29, 37, 46, 56 — this sequence is the triangular numbers plus 1. (Note the triangular Numbers are 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55...)

So then the answer ought to be

> 10 = 1110, as 111 is the 56th positive odd number and 10 x 111 = 1110.

Comment: You are probably on the right track, but maybe insisting on primes isn't necessary?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you’re right — this fits better I think. Thanks for the heads up, @Bass

Comment: No not the right answer

Comment: As it turns out, my process IS right, I’m just a dumdum.

Comment: Congrats on having the right process, but too bad for the miscount.

Comment: I gave you an upvote for being modest

Answer (score 3):

I came to the same conclusion as the others through a different method maybe, sorry if this is exactly what someone else said or I use some funky syntax:

I noted that

> 3/1 = 3
> 14/2 = 7
> 39/3 = 13
> 84/4 = 21
> 155/5 = 31
> The difference between the RHS of each group increases by 2 each time.

Therefore:

> Extrapolating the differences (up to 10) we get:
>  12, 14, 16, 18 and 20
>  Adding the differences to the RHs of the first set of equations starting from the last one (31), results in 111

The answer should be:

> 1,110, since 111 * 10 = 1,110

I feel like I probably didn't do a great job of explaining this and if that's the case, apologies but I'm new to this community and I'm not very familiar with how questions should be answered.

Comment: Yes I remembered when designing this puzzle seeing that pattern, that is why I subsequently scrambled the order of the numbers but you still managed to see it. Have an upvote!